# OpenCVSharp - Compare two images, and return back the matched area with coordinates

Tags: c#, image, opencv

Its been awhile since I have posted on here and I am finally getting a little time to work on a personal project again.

I just started working with for the first time today, OpenCVSharp in C# .NET 4.8 and working on a small code spike.

I have found samples online as OpenCVSharp has a nice examples library; however I am uncertain as to which one of them would point me in the right direction. I started off using their SIFT/SURF one.

So what I am trying to do is as follows:

1.) Image1 is a picture which is a full resolution image (3440x1440).

2.) Image2 is a cropped picture from Image1, which is what I will use as the target to find and identify in Image1.

3.) Return back the pixel coordinates of the rectangular or square area "my boundries".

4.) Return back or calculate the dead center of the rectangular or square area.

Thank you all in advance for any help and support on this topic!

EDIT:
After being informed to try keypoint matching, I found that the https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_samples/blob/master/SamplesCS/Samples/DrawBestMatch.cs works exactly as I need it to.

The part where I am now stuck is trying to figure out the exact pixel location from the returned match image, on the original. I get back the matched image which is great, however I am trying to figure out step #3 in my original post now.
[image]

Comment: give keypoint matching a try: SIFT / SURF / ORB are most used ones. matchTemplate or Optical Flow could work as well, but as often in computer vision: Whether a rechnique works or nor depends on the assumptions and requirements of the actual image content and environmrnt.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on keypoint matching!

I looked through the samples and identified by logic what appeared to be doing a keypoint map and comparison based on distance. From that I found the following example works like a charm: https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_samples/blob/master/SamplesCS/Samples/DrawBestMatch.cs

So now when I give it image1 which is what I want to find a match within, with image2 'the thing I am looking for' it worked! 

Now I am trying to figure out how to identify what the actual pixel point is for the rectangle being returned.